# Query that looks for current user in table? php, sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am using php to query a sql db/table to retrieve a message which is on the same row as the current user.

I want to write  a query that looks for the current session user in the table, and displays all info in all rows matching their username.

```
$user = $_SESSION["sess_user"];
    $sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Mail WHERE recipient_username ='".$user."'");
```

i cannot find the proper arrangement of fetching and displaying, and could use a pointer! thank you for your time.

I have been looking for the answer to this, and I'm sure there is one out there, so if someone has a link, it is more than welcome.

Comment: share `print_r($user)` value ?

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

```
i got it. thanks guys. 


$user = $_SESSION["sess_user"];
    $sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Mail WHERE recipient_username ='".$user."'");


if($sql){
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Mail WHERE recipient_username ='".$user."'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result)){
    echo'<table border="1" ><th >Message Date</th><th>Sender</th><th>message</th>';
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['msg_date'].'</td>';   
    echo '<td>' .$row['sender_username']. '</td>';
       echo '<td>' .$row['sender_message'].'</td>   </tr>' ;
    echo '</table>';
```